# Passing JSON to backend(c#) using node.js

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, express

I am trying to pass data from user input at the frontend to my backend. In my front end I am using JavaScript and backend C#. I have successfully implemented the GET request by the following:

**in api**

```
api.getTestData = function (req, res) {
var dataId = req.params.ddataId;
var ndataId = parseInt(dataId)
var data = 
{
test1: 'hi'
};

var jsData = {
jsInteger: dataId,
jsNumber: 9.87654,
jsString: 'JS Data',
jsBoolean: true,
jsBuffer: new Buffer(10),
jsArray: [1, 'JS element'],
jsObject: { a: 'JS object', b: 12 }
     };

dotNetGetTestData(jsData, function (error, result)
{
data.test1 = result.test1;
res.send(data);
return;
});
};
```

**in c#**

```
        IDictionary<string, object> jsData = (IDictionary<string, object>)input;


        int localInteger = (int)jsData["jsInteger"];
        double localNumber = (double)jsData["jsNumber"];
        string localString = (string)jsData["jsString"];
        bool localBoolean = (bool)jsData["jsBoolean"];
        byte[] localBuffer = (byte[])jsData["jsBuffer"];
        object[] localArray = (object[])jsData["jsArray"];
        IDictionary<string, object> localObject = (IDictionary<string,                               object>)jsData["jsObject"];

testData.test1 = "hello";
```

My issue is passing JSON from node to my backend.

Comment: what is res?  I see res.send, but no definition for res.  I expected ajax somewhere also or are you sending it to the backend some other way?

Comment: Updated the code, this example is of Getting data from backend. I am now trying to put new data from the user input to the backend

Comment: What is the name of the method?  Is this web forms or mvc?

Comment: Hope are you passing data to .net. Are you using edgejs?

Comment: Yes I am mapping c# methods to js functions using edge